# Check if variable is set to NO_VALUE

Tags: python, python-2.7, dogpile.cache

I am using dogpile to have cache in my python program.
During the init of my program, I clean the cache `SimpleCache.set_fault_injector(NO_VALUE)`

```
@staticmethod
def set_fault_injector(injector):
    SimpleCache.save("fault_injector", injector)
```

Then I retrieve the object with:

```
@staticmethod
def get_fault_injector():
    return SimpleCache.get("fault_injector")

injector = get_fault_injector()
```

Here in my test, I am checking if the `injector` variable is set to `NO_VALUE`, but the comparison is returning `False` (it should be `TRUE`). How do I check if `injector` is set to `NO_VALUE`? The way that I clear the cache is correct?

```
In [3]: injector
Out[3]: <dogpile.cache.api.NoValue at 0x7fdde0dfd750>

In [4]: NO_VALUE
Out[4]: <dogpile.cache.api.NoValue at 0x7fdde16dbed0>

In [5]: injector == NO_VALUE
Out[5]: False

In [6]: type(injector)
Out[6]: dogpile.cache.api.NoValue

In [7]: type(NO_VALUE)
Out[7]: dogpile.cache.api.NoValue

In [8]: injector is NO_VALUE
Out[8]: False

[9]: type(injector) == type(NO_VALUE)
Out[9]: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience in dogpile, however, from what I understand from the docs, when a value is missing then dogpile normally returns a specific instance of `dogpile.cache.api.NoValue`, which is `NO_CACHE`.

The issue here is probably linked to you explicitly setting a cache key to `NO_CACHE`, which somehow ends up leaving you with 2 different instances of the `NoValue` class.

It appears to me that `NO_CACHE` is not really meant to be used for unsetting a key, I believe your issue would be resolved if you actually used `.delete("fault_injector")` or whatever removal method your cache wrapper has available.